# Matching a string to an Array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, list

Sorry for the wall of text ahead of time. So for an assignment in my class, I have to program a fast food menu and I'm having trouble with the delete ordered item button. What should happen is I select an item from one of four lists than "order" it by either pressing a button or double-clicking. The problem that I'm having is I can't find a way to remove the price and item from the ordered item list. I'm thinking the problem lies in the getItemLoc method but I can't see what's wrong. This is what I cooked up but it's not working.

```
    // Arrays of selection items
static final String[] JUNK_FOODS = {"Burger", "Hotdog", "Fries", "Pizza"};
static final int[] JUNK_FOODS_PRICE = {199, 150, 99, 299};
static final String[] DESSERTS = {"Ice cream", "Pie", "Cake", "Donut"};
static final int[] DESSERTS_PRICE = {149, 249, 299, 99};
static final String[] FRUIT = {"Apple", "Orange", "Peach", "Banana"};
static final int[] FRUIT_PRICE = {89, 79, 99, 59};
static final String[] BEVERAGE = {"Soda", "Coffee", "Juice", "Water"};
static final int[] BEVERAGE_PRICE = {85, 95, 75, 55};

else if(event.getSource() == deleteItem) { // remove item from ordered list
            selectedIndex = itemsOrderedList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedItem = itemsOrderedList.getSelectedItem();
            getItemLoc(selectedItem, selectedIndex);
        }

/**
 *  method to remove an ordered item
 */
void removeOrderedItem(String item, int price) {
    itemsOrderedList.remove(item);
    amount -= price;
    amountLabel.setText("$"+(float)amount/100);
}

/**
 *  method to find what list an item belongs to
 */
void getItemLoc(String item, int price) {
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(JUNK_FOODS[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, JUNK_FOODS_PRICE[i]);
        }
        else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(DESSERTS[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, DESSERTS_PRICE[i]);
        }
        else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(FRUIT[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, FRUIT_PRICE[i]);
        }
        else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(BEVERAGE[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, BEVERAGE_PRICE[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

I brought it to my professor and he told me that it wasn't finding any matches which is why the program isn't working but before I could ask why we had to leave as there was another class coming in.
I'll put the rest of the program down here so you can see the whole thing and test it if you want to. It's probably something that's super simple and I'm just not seeing it but thank you for taking a look, have a nice day.

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class FastFood extends Frame {

// Initial Frame size
static final int WIDTH = 450;                // frame width
static final int HEIGHT = 400;               // frame height

// Arrays of selection items
static final String[] JUNK_FOODS = {"Burger", "Hotdog", "Fries", "Pizza"};
static final int[] JUNK_FOODS_PRICE = {199, 150, 99, 299};
static final String[] DESSERTS = {"Ice cream", "Pie", "Cake", "Donut"};
static final int[] DESSERTS_PRICE = {149, 249, 299, 99};
static final String[] FRUIT = {"Apple", "Orange", "Peach", "Banana"};
static final int[] FRUIT_PRICE = {89, 79, 99, 59};
static final String[] BEVERAGE = {"Soda", "Coffee", "Juice", "Water"};
static final int[] BEVERAGE_PRICE = {85, 95, 75, 55};

// List and Button control
List junkFoodList;
List dessertList;
List fruitList;
List beverageList;
List itemsOrderedList;
Button addJunkFood;
Button addDessert;
Button addFruit;
Button addBeverage;
Button deleteItem;
Button clearAll;

// Total amount and display
Label amountLabel;
int amount = 0;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public FastFood() {
    setTitle("Fast Food To Go");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    // create display for item selection
    Panel itemPanel = new Panel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
    add(itemPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // create display and control for junk food selection items
    Panel junkFoodPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    itemPanel.add(junkFoodPanel);
    Label junkFood = new Label("Fast Food Items", Label.CENTER);
    junkFood.setForeground(Color.red);
    junkFoodPanel.add(junkFood, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    junkFoodList = new List();
    for(int i=0; i<JUNK_FOODS.length; i++) {
        junkFoodList.add(JUNK_FOODS[i]+ "   $" + (float)JUNK_FOODS_PRICE[i]/100);
    }
    junkFoodPanel.add(junkFoodList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Panel buttonPanel = new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    junkFoodPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addJunkFood = new Button("Get Food Item");
    buttonPanel.add(addJunkFood);

    // create display and control for dessert selection items
    Panel dessertPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    itemPanel.add(dessertPanel);
    Label dessertLabel = new Label("Dessert Items", Label.CENTER);
    dessertLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    dessertPanel.add(dessertLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    dessertList = new List();
    for(int i=0; i<DESSERTS.length; i++) {
        dessertList.add(DESSERTS[i]+ "   $" + (float)DESSERTS_PRICE[i]/100);
    }
    dessertPanel.add(dessertList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel = new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    dessertPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addDessert = new Button("Get Dessert Item");
    buttonPanel.add(addDessert);

    // create display and control for fruit selection items
    Panel fruitPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    itemPanel.add(fruitPanel);
    Label fruitLabel = new Label("Fruit Items", Label.CENTER);
    fruitLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    fruitPanel.add(fruitLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    fruitList = new List();
    for(int i=0; i<FRUIT.length; i++) {
        fruitList.add(FRUIT[i] + "  $" + (float)FRUIT_PRICE[i]/100);
    }
    fruitPanel.add(fruitList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel = new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    fruitPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addFruit = new Button("Get Fruit Item");
    buttonPanel.add(addFruit);

    // create display and control for beverage selection items
    Panel beveragePanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    itemPanel.add(beveragePanel);
    Label beverageLabel = new Label("Beverage Items", Label.CENTER);
    beverageLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
    beveragePanel.add(beverageLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    beverageList = new List();
    for(int i=0; i<BEVERAGE.length; i++) {
        beverageList.add(BEVERAGE[i] + "  $" + (float)BEVERAGE_PRICE[i]/100);
    }
    beveragePanel.add(beverageList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel = new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    beveragePanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    addBeverage = new Button("Get Beverage Item");
    buttonPanel.add(addBeverage);

    // create display and control for items ordered and amount
    Panel orderedPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    add(orderedPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    // create display and control for items ordered
    Panel itemsOrderedPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    orderedPanel.add(itemsOrderedPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    Label itemsOrdered = new Label("Items Ordered", Label.CENTER);
    itemsOrdered.setForeground(Color.red);
    itemsOrderedPanel.add(itemsOrdered, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    itemsOrderedList = new List();
    itemsOrderedPanel.add(itemsOrderedList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    buttonPanel = new Panel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    itemsOrderedPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    deleteItem = new Button("Delete Ordered Item");
    buttonPanel.add(deleteItem);
    clearAll = new Button("Clear All");
    buttonPanel.add(clearAll);

    // create display for amount
    Panel amountPanel = new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    orderedPanel.add(amountPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Label totalLabel = new Label("Total Amount: ");
    amountPanel.add(totalLabel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    amountLabel = new Label("$0.00");
    amountPanel.add(amountLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    // create and add list selection listener
    SelectionListener selListener = new SelectionListener();
    junkFoodList.addActionListener(selListener);
    dessertList.addActionListener(selListener);
    fruitList.addActionListener(selListener);
    beverageList.addActionListener(selListener);
    itemsOrderedList.addActionListener(selListener);
    clearAll.addActionListener(selListener);


    // create and add button listener
    ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
    addJunkFood.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    addDessert.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    addFruit.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    addBeverage.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    deleteItem.addActionListener(buttonListener);
    clearAll.addActionListener(buttonListener);
} // end of constructor

/**
 *  Listener class for list selection
 */
class SelectionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String selectedItem;
        int selectedIndex;
        int itemPrice;

        if(event.getSource() == junkFoodList) {  // select item from junk food list
            selectedIndex = junkFoodList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedItem = junkFoodList.getSelectedItem();
            itemPrice = JUNK_FOODS_PRICE[selectedIndex];
            addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == dessertList) {  // select item from dessert list
            selectedIndex = dessertList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedItem = dessertList.getSelectedItem();
            itemPrice = DESSERTS_PRICE[selectedIndex];
            addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == fruitList) {  // select item from fruit list
            selectedIndex = fruitList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedItem = fruitList.getSelectedItem();
            itemPrice = FRUIT_PRICE[selectedIndex];
            addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == beverageList) { // select item from beverage list
            selectedIndex = beverageList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedItem = beverageList.getSelectedItem();
            itemPrice = BEVERAGE_PRICE[selectedIndex];
            addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == deleteItem) { // remove item from ordered list
            selectedIndex = itemsOrderedList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedItem = itemsOrderedList.getSelectedItem();
            getItemLoc(selectedItem, selectedIndex);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clearAll) { // remove everything from ordered list
            itemsOrderedList.removeAll();
            amount = 0;
            amountLabel.setText("$0.00");
        }
    }
}

/**
 *  Listener class for button selection
 */
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String selectedItem;
        int selectedIndex;
        int itemPrice;

        if(event.getSource() == addJunkFood) {  // get item from junk food list
            selectedIndex = junkFoodList.getSelectedIndex();
            if(selectedIndex >= 0) {
                selectedItem = junkFoodList.getSelectedItem();
                itemPrice = JUNK_FOODS_PRICE[selectedIndex];
                addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
            }
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == addDessert) {  // get item from dessert list
            selectedIndex = dessertList.getSelectedIndex();
            if(selectedIndex >= 0) {
                selectedItem = dessertList.getSelectedItem();
                itemPrice = DESSERTS_PRICE[selectedIndex];
                addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
            }
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == addFruit) {  // get item from fruit list
            selectedIndex = fruitList.getSelectedIndex();
            if(selectedIndex >= 0) {
                selectedItem = fruitList.getSelectedItem();
                itemPrice = FRUIT_PRICE[selectedIndex];
                addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
            }
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == addBeverage) {  // get item from beverage list
            selectedIndex = fruitList.getSelectedIndex();
            if(selectedIndex >= 0) {
                selectedItem = beverageList.getSelectedItem();
                itemPrice = BEVERAGE_PRICE[selectedIndex];
                addOrderedItem(selectedItem, itemPrice);
            }
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == deleteItem) {  // delete item from ordered list
            selectedIndex = itemsOrderedList.getSelectedIndex();
            selectedItem = itemsOrderedList.getSelectedItem();
            getItemLoc(selectedItem, selectedIndex);
        }
        else if(event.getSource() == clearAll) { // remove everything from ordered list
            itemsOrderedList.removeAll();
            amount = 0;
            amountLabel.setText("$0.00");
        }
    }
}

/**
 *  method to add an ordered item
 */
void addOrderedItem(String item, int price) {
    itemsOrderedList.add(item);
    amount += price;
    amountLabel.setText("$"+(float)amount/100);
}

/**
 *  method to remove an ordered item
 */
void removeOrderedItem(String item, int price) {
    itemsOrderedList.remove(item);
    amount -= price;
    amountLabel.setText("$"+(float)amount/100);
}

/**
 *  method to find what list an item belongs to
 */
void getItemLoc(String item, int price) {
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(JUNK_FOODS[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, JUNK_FOODS_PRICE[i]);
        }
        else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(DESSERTS[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, DESSERTS_PRICE[i]);
        }
        else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(FRUIT[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, FRUIT_PRICE[i]);
        }
        else if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(BEVERAGE[i])) {
            removeOrderedItem(item, BEVERAGE_PRICE[i]);
        }
    }

}

/**
 * the main method
 */
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    // Create a frame
    FastFood frame = new FastFood();
    frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    frame.setLocation(450, 400);

    // add window closing listener
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    // Show the frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Debug this code and ensure that the arguments being passed into `getItemLoc` are correct (either use a debugger or simply a print statement).  It should be the `item` and the `price`, but the `price` is never used.

Comment: Your comment "method to find what list an item belongs to" (and the method name itself) is misleading, since the method actually seems to remove items from a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add Strings to your `orderItemsList` you add the item plus the price

e.g.

```
Pizza $2.99
```

So when you click on `deleteItem` and get the selected text you get the whole String and code like

```
if(item.equalsIgnoreCase(JUNK_FOODS[i])) {
```

fails.

To be honest you can just parse this String to get both the item and the price, so change to

```
void getItemLoc(String item, int price) {
    removeOrderedItem (item, price);
}

void removeOrderedItem(String item, int price) {
   itemsOrderedList.remove(item);
   amount -= price;
   amountLabel.setText("$"+(float)amount/100);
}
```

**Note**

I am sure that the `price` being passed in is not the price but the `selected index`

This can be dealt with by first removing the redundant `price` argument and changing the code to

```
void removeOrderedItem(String item) {
 itemsOrderedList.remove(item);
 String strprice = item.split("   ")[1];
 strprice = strprice.replace("$", "");
 int price = (int) (Float.parseFloat(strprice) * 100);
 amount -= price;
 amountLabel.setText("$"+(float)amount/100);
}
```